# Mock net/http Transport understanding problems

Tags: go

I am new to go and run into some understanding problems with go interfaces and mock.

I have written a module that uses net/http to perform some HTTP actions. Now I like to add some unit tests but struggling with interfaces and mocks.
My package looks like

```
package myhttp

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

// HTTPClient interface
type HTTPClient interface {
    Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

var (
    Client HTTPClient
)

func init() {
    Client = &http.Client{}
}

func Fetch (url string) ( *http.Response, error) {
    //tlsCfg := tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: false}
    tr := &http.Transport{
        IdleConnTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        TLSClientConfig:    &tlsCfg,
    }
    req,err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodHead,url,nil)
    resp, err := Client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return  nil, err
    }
    return resp, nil
}
```

My Mock

```
package httputils

import "net/http"
// MockClient is the mock client
type MockClient struct {
    DoFunc func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)

}

var (
    // GetDoFunc fetches the mock client's `Do` func
    GetDoFunc func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
)


// Do is the mock client's `Do` func
func (m *MockClient) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return GetDoFunc(req)
```

}
I need to configure the transport to be able to set Timeouts and the TLS config but .Transport is a struct that will be initialized if I crate the Client's instance and not be set later. How can I create an interface for this to be able to mock this?

Comment: Why are you trying to mock HTTP? You can definitely create an `http.RoundTripper`, which is already an interface, but what exactly is the goal here?

Comment: My goal is to be able to set  Timeouts and  the used TLS settings  (in the fetch function) and be  able  to mock the request for testing  the fetch function

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to use a mock at all here. All of these components are individually test-able, and you can make actual requests to an httptest server to verify them as a whole.